# Are there any alternatives to the Epicentre product Plasmid Safe?

Tags: dna, enzymes, plasmids, materials

I need to remove any traces of linear DNA (both single and double stranded) from a ligation reaction while keeping circular DNA intact. Up to now, I have used [Epicentre's Plasmid Safe](http://www.epibio.com/docs/default-source/protocols/plasmid-safe-atp-dependent-dnase.pdf) to do the job. I would like to try another solution (mostly because of the unreliability of our supplier: it takes weeks to get a batch!).

Has anyone replaced Plasmid Safe with other nucleases? Which one?
I have been looking at the [NEB nucleases](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/selection-charts/properties-of-exonucleases-and-endonucleases) and I was thinking to use ExoV and T together to get rid of any linear DNA (both ssDNA and dsDNA). Does anyone have any other solution to propose?

Comment: *"any other solution"* How about separating them on a gel?

Comment: I would like to avoid gel-purification, the input DNA is already low, plus, some linear DNA is running at the same height of the circular one. I really need to digest specifically the linear ss and ds DNA.

Comment: alec_djinn, did combining ExoV and T work for you? I am also looking for methods alternative to Plasmid Safe. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it worked. All the linear DNA is digested. But be careful to do not let the reaction go too long. In my case, 15 min was enough to digest 500 ng with 5 units of both enzymes. Try it out.